# Ansible builtin git hanging forever, but same task with command git clone works

Tags: git, ansible

I'm trying to use the builtin git for ansible and it just hangs forever. If I didn't know better I would think that it's hanging on a password prompt. The strange thing is if I take the exact same variables and just use command it works fine, so I know the variables are not a problem. What I'm seeing is the following code hang:

```
- name: pull via git
  git: 
    repo: "https://{{ gitUser | urlencode }}:{{ gitPass | urlencode }}@{{ gitUrl }}"
    dest: "{{ gitDir }}"
    clone: true
```

However, if I comment the above out and use the following:

```
- name: pull via git
  command: "git clone https://{{ gitUser | urlencode }}:{{ gitPass | urlencode }}@{{ gitUrl }} {{ gitDir }}"
```

The task works flawlessly. Obviously I have to be missing something while using the ansible git builtin but I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Any one got any suggestions?

Comment: Did you notice the [Notes section](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/ansible/builtin/git_module.html#notes) that addresses common causes for that task to hang? If you ssh into that host and `kill -INT` the `git` process, it'll cause ansible to actually return the output it _did_ get, which can be helpful in troubleshooting also

Comment: The notes section refers to hanging due to a known_hosts prompt, which would only occur for pulling via SSH. This is pulling via HTTPS so that wouldn't apply. However ... killing the git on the remote server and forcing the output is an excellent idea, I'll have to give that a shot and see if it gives any insight.